# Installing from deb files vs run file

Tags: installation, installer, deb

If an app publishers offers both a deb file/ repo based installation, as well as a run file, which is preferable, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say repositories are the *best* option simply because it lets you update. deb/rpm/packages allow you to install and uninstall 'cleanly' with native tools.

With a run file, its generally a script that *does stuff* and you'd need the same script to *possibly* uninstall.

A more modern approach (which I'm not entirely fond of) would be containers - either int the style of snap or flatpack, which have the same advantages as a 'native' package, or shipping as a docker or another container. You have a tested, consistent working setup of the software/software stack to start, as the developer intended. However its a little difficult in some cases to customise the install to your needs, and sometimes a little bulkier